# how to make html5 drop bubble

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I've a parent and some children to drop.
when I drop on a child the drop fire on the child,but i want it to fire on the parent.
As in the example below, I want the e.target to be ul,not li.
I know we can bubble event, but it seems not work facing html5 drop.
Is there any way to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testDrag</title>
  <style>
    section {
      float: left;
      background: black;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-right: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    div {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      background: #ddd;
      border: 3px red solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="3">3</div>
    <div id="4">4</div>
    <div id="5">5</div>
    <div id="6">6</div>
    <div id="7">7</div>
  </section>
  <section id="des">
    </ul>
    <script>
      var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var temp = divs[i];
        temp.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        temp.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
      }

      function handleDragStart(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('ID', this.id);
      }
      var des = document.getElementById("des");
      des.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragEnter, false);
      des.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

      function handleDragEnter(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }

      function handleDrop(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        e.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('ID')));
      }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first drop a li in the ul next to ul in the left. then drop a another li into the dropped li.I want the e.target to be ul,not li.

Comment: So the result may be li and ul. Not only a li.